# reading data from Express Server after making Axios call in ReactJS, Spotify API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, spotify

My goal is to retrieve the data from the endpoint https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks. I've setup an express server to handle routing and here is the endpoint.

```
app.get('/api/top/tracks', (req, res) => {

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks',
    data: queryString.stringify({
      limit: 30,
      offset: 0,
      time_range: 'medium_term'
    }),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedPayload,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
    res.json(response.data)
 }).catch(error => console.log(error.response))
})
```

In another React functional component, I am trying to read the value in a useEffect, something like this.

```
  const [topTracks, setTopTracks] = useState(tracks)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTopTracks() {
      const response = await fetch('/api/top/tracks');
      const json = await response.json();
      setTopTracks(json);
    }

    getTopTracks();

  }, []);
```

In all honesty I think I just don't understand the Response Promise object from API calls and am not sure how to handle the data I am attempting to retrieve.

[image]

EDIT: Appended .catch to the end of axios call. But now I receive a very long error response for an HTTP error 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pointing to your local express server, then your fetch call from your react component needs to point to the full url. Right now, your component's `useEffect` is unable to resolve to the correct endpoint, i.e. the express server

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/top/tracks');
```

*Note that depending on where your express server is hosted on, you might have to replace the localhost portion of the url*

Comment: In my App.js I am using something similar to get a token value and I don't have this issue with the pathing

Comment: From your browser logs, it looks like you are unable to hit your express server from your browser. Suggest that you do a curl from your terminal to the express server first to check your endpoints